# SQL select data from multiple tables with subqueries (including data from inner join) Error: 1242

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery, mysql-error-1242

I want to display the ID from Table1 (TID) and the results of an inner join.
The following statement is not working.

**Situation**: Two Tables:

- Table 1 PK:TID, FK: Table2_PID
- Table2 PK: PID, Name

Among other data I want to display the Name of every PID in Table1 which is stored in Table2.

```
SELECT T.TID 
    ,(Select P.Name
        from mydb.Table2 P
        inner join mydb.Table1 T
        on P.PID=T.Table2_PID) 
    FROM mydb.Ticket T;

Result: Error Code 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

I do know that the result returns more than 1 row, but I want to show the Name of every PID in Table1 which is stored in Table2. So any ideas on how I can do that?

PS: I'm using mySQL and working with MySQL Workbench v6.3

Comment: Your second select statement belongs in the FROM as a derived table.

Comment: how is your `ticket` table is related to `table2` or `table1` ?

Comment: Yeah, sorry Ticket is Table1

Answer (score 0):

You don't need use the inner joins for getting all the names of the ID. You can try the default join to achieve the result.

```
select t2.pid, t2.name from mydb.Table2 t2, mydb.Table1 t1 where t1.pid = t2.pid;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You must use join like this

```
select t1.TID,t2.Name from Table1 t1 left join Table2 t2 on t1.Table2_PID=t2.PID
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response, but the question/problem still remains.
It wasn't about the join.

**It is about the subquery and selecting multiple rows within it.**

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys,
I was thinking of a solution way to complicated. I resolved it using a simple where statement.

```
SELECT T.TID, P.Name
FROM mydb.table1 T, mydb.table2 P
WHERE P.PID=T.table2_PID;
```